# MongoDB Yii extension with PHP warning missing php file Mongo

Tags: mongodb, yii, yii-extensions

I have created a new app using the `yii` framework and I want to use `MongoDB`.

I used this: [mongodb yii extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimongodbsuite/#c9724)

I configured the app as the tutorial shows, I wrote a model class and when I tryed to insert data, I got a warning: php file missing !

The following [video](http://screencast.com/t/GuMsojzD6IYr) shows details;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the answer;

It turned out that wamp was missing the php mongo dll file.

I found it and downloaded from:

[github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads)

Yii with MongoDB extension works fine now;